# How can i complete gradient descent algorithm code?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am freshman & beginner.

I am studying machine learning with open tutorials.

I have a trouble with making gradient descent algorithm

I have to complete "`for _ in range(max_iter):`"  but, I don't know about `numpy`... so I don't know  what code should i add 
Could you please help me fill the blank?

I know this type of question is so rude... sorry but I need your help :(
Thank you in advance.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = datasets.make_classification(
n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, random_state = 333,
n_informative =2, n_redundant = 0  , n_clusters_per_class= 1)

def sigmoid(s):
     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

def loss(y, h):
     return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()

def gradient(X, y, w):
     return -(y * X) / (1 + np.exp(-y * np.dot(X, w)))


X_bias = np.append(np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X, axis=1)
y = np.array([[1] if label == 0 else [0] for label in y])
w = np.array([[random.uniform(-1, 1)] for _ in range(X.shape[1]+1)])
max_iter = 100
learning_rate = 0.1
threshold = 0.5
for _ in range(max_iter):
#fill in the blank
what code should i add ????


probabilities = sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias, w))
predictions = [[1] if p > threshold else [0] for p in probabilities]
print("loss: %.2f, accuracy: %.2f" %
(loss(y, probabilities), accuracy_score(y, predictions)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, we have to first compute the probabilities. Then find the gradients and then update the weights.

For computing probabilities, you can use the code below

```
probs=sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias,w))
```

`np.dot` is numpy command for matrix multiplication. Then we will calculate the loss and its gradients.

```
J=loss(y,probs)
dJ=gradient(X_bias,y,w)
```

Now we will update the weights.

```
w=w-learning_rate*dJ
```

So the final code will be

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = datasets.make_classification(
n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, random_state = 333,
n_informative =2, n_redundant = 0  , n_clusters_per_class= 1)

def sigmoid(s):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

def loss(y, h):
    return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()

def gradient(X, y, w):
    return -(y * X) / (1 + np.exp(-y * np.dot(X, w)))


X_bias = np.append(np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X, axis=1)
y = np.array([[1] if label == 0 else [0] for label in y])
w = np.array([[np.random.uniform(-1, 1)] for _ in range(X.shape[1]+1)])
max_iter = 100
learning_rate = 0.1
threshold = 0.5
for _ in range(max_iter):
    probs=sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias,w))
    J=loss(y,probs)
    dJ=gradient(X_bias,y,w)
    w=w-learning_rate*dJ
probabilities = sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias, w))
predictions = [[1] if p > threshold else [0] for p in probabilities]
print("loss: %.2f, accuracy: %.2f" %
(loss(y, probabilities), accuracy_score(y, predictions)))
```

Note: In the `for` loop, there is no need to compute probs and loss, As we only need gradients to update the weights. I did that because it will be easy to understand.